# Send Large XML object in AJAX POST Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, sapui5

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEtHH.png)I am facing issue while Sending the XML document with POST method.
I want to upload the file VIA SAP MII transaction and for that first i am converting the File content into Base 64 format with the help of File reader. After that as SAP MII transaction requested i converted the complete Base 64 string into 255 length of chucks and then Built an XML document which was accepted when i trying to send the same data from the transaction side.

But when i am sending the data from UI with the AJAX POST method the Data is not sent to the beckend.

Please see my below code.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  cache: false,
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,

  url: "/XMII/Runner?Transaction=New_POD_UI5/Transactions/FileUploader/BLS_FileUploader&OutputParameter=OutputXML",
  data: xmlDocument,
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(result) {
    //code
    sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.hide();
    sap.m.MessageBox.information("success");
  },
  complete: function() {
    sap.ui.getCore().byId("fileUploader").setValue("");
    sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.hide();
  },
  error: function() {
    sap.m.MessageBox.error("File upload failed");
  },
  beforeSend: function() {
    sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.show();[Image for data posting in Request header][1]
  }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul8Ci.png)

Comment: Keep in mind that `dataType: "xml",` is saying the ajax request is expected to return xml. To tell the backend that the data is xml you would use the `contentType` option. How are you verifying that the request is not sending the xml to the backend?

Comment: i am checking with the Event logger that triggers, whenever it sends the data to the beckend. whenever i am triggering this POST ajax, everytime i get into success.. when i try to upload large files (ex >7MB ) the file data gets converted successfylly but the request payload get empty

Comment: Verify in your Developer Tools Network tab if the contents are sent or not

Comment: yes..i checked it .. for large files...XML Document is large so its not getting sent to the beckend.. is there any limit ..how large data we can send in AJAX POST content ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: The web server may reject large files (IIS does this for example).  Check the maximum file size that the web server supports.

Comment: Did you find any workaround for this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Isn't there the information about the transaction parameter missing which is supposed to contain the data? Have you tried adding `InputParameter=<name of target transaction parameter>` to the url? Have you tried the same thing with a small xml?